# Round tripping between Flash Catalyst and Flash Builder for Android apps

Tags: android, flash, builder, flashcatalyst

Is there any way to "round trip" Android projects between Flash Catalyst and Flash Builder? I'm using the latest beta versions (Burrito and Panini).

If not, will this be available with CS5.5 when it's released next month?

Answer (score 0):

You can round-trip between Catalyst CS 5.5 and Flash Builder 4.5 (most recent versions). However, the project has to be a "Flash Catalyst Compatible Project", which by definition is a Flex project, not an AIR or Mobile project. I set up 3 projects:

- A "Skin" project, Flash Catalyst Compatible and contains the UI code. There's nothing in Main.mxml; the bulk of the app is contained in a Custom Component (and child components).
- A "Core" project, which imports the source from the Skin project and runs unit tests against it. This is also where I can import from other source libraries.
- A "Mobile" project, which imports the source from the Core and Skin projects, and is the actual project you build from for mobile. It contains almost no code except for an application MXML file which instantiates the app component in the "Skin" project.